# To see the pcl result of mnist, I want to return the hidden layer of dnn in numpy format

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to store 'input'(x) and z[1] values((self.fc1(x.view(-1, self.in_dim)))) and a[1] as variables inside a forward function. After that, I want to return it with logit and save it in NumPy format. Or I want to convert the result from tensor to numpy format and save it.
How can I save with NumPy?

Below is an example code similar to mine

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.in_dim = 28 * 28
    self.out_dim = 10

    self.fc1 =nn.Linear(self.in_dim,512)
    self.fc2=nn.Linear(512, 256)
    self.fc3 =nn.Linear(256, 128)
    self.fc4 =nn.Linear(128, 64)
    self.fc5 =nn.Linear(64, self.out_dim)

    self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
      print("x",x.shape)
      a1 = self.relu(self.fc1(x.view(-1,self.in_dim)))
      print("a1",a1.shape)
      a2 = self.relu(self.fc2(a1))
      a3 = self.relu(self.fc2(a2))
      a4 = self.relu(self.fc2(a3))
      logit = self.fc5(a4)

      return logit
```

Comment: It is not clear what `z[1]` is, are you referring to `a1`?. Can you be clearer on what you want exactly?

Comment: Both!
I thought the way to store a variable and save it from return to numpy would be the same.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions. Can you tell what `z[1]` is precisely? Which intermediate outputs do you want to return?

Comment: Oh, the z[1] value means (self.fc1(x.view(-1, self.in_dim))

Answer (score 0):

You can return both a1 and logits out of the forward function:

```
def forward(self, x):
    a1 = self.relu(self.fc1(x.view(-1,self.in_dim)))
    a2 = self.relu(self.fc2(a1))
    a3 = self.relu(self.fc2(a2))
    a4 = self.relu(self.fc2(a3))
    logit = self.fc5(a4)

    return a1, logit
```

Comment: The problem is returning it and then saving it in numpy format.

Comment: Then you can do `np.save(filepath, a1.numpy())`.